# I cannot connect to a database using RJDBC and Rscript using the windows terminal

Tags: r, windows, oracle, ojdbc, rscript

I am trying to run a script in R, using Rscript in the windows terminal, however I have the following problem when trying to connect to an oracle database using RJDBC

This is the code I use for my connections and where the problem occurs

```
driver <- JDBC('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver',classPath = '../source/setup/ojdbc8.jar')

conn <- RJDBC::dbConnect(driver, jdbc:oracle:thin@<host>:<port>/servicename, conn_user, conn_paswd)
```

and the error is as follows using Rscript in the windows terminal:

`Error in .local(drv, ...) : Unable to connect JDBC to Calls:  source ... <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> .local -> .verify.JDBC.result Execution halted`

When I run the code on Rstudio, it works fine, just when I run on the terminal I face the issue

Any ideas?